# Process starvation test case on XINU

Tags: operating-system, scheduler, priority-queue, xinu

I am trying to produce a test case for demonstrating starvation by xinu's default scheduling policy.: if 2 processes are ready for execution, the one with higher priority keeps running and if processes have equal priority than round robin algo.

The rough idea is to create 2 processes with different priority. This creation puts both the process in suspended state. After this, we call the resume sys call for process 1 which puts it into readylist schedule queue which then calls reschedule sys call which executes it.

Since xinu cant run in parallel, only after proc 1 is complete, the same happens for proc 2. Thus, I cant seems to figure out how to demonstrate starvation in xinu. I know it occurs, but i have trouble thinking a way around this.

Answer (score 0):

You can try having the first process run an infinite loop. As long as its priority is higher than the 2nd process, the 2nd wouldn't get any processing time.